# How change format mask in XMLELEMENT function from Oracle DB 11g CORE 11.2.0.3.0?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, type-conversion, dml

I use function XMLELEMENT and XMLATTRIBUTES in my sql query, but I have problems with format date.
Example:

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT("triggers", XMLATTRIBUTES(3.2 AS "version"), 
   XMLELEMENT("request", XMLATTRIBUTES(1 AS "num"),     
   XMLELEMENT("lastname", trigg.last_name),
   XMLELEMENT("firstname", trigg.first_name),
   XMLELEMENT("middlename", trigg.middle_name),
   XMLELEMENT("birthday", trigg.birth_date).....
```

Field XMLELEMENT("birthday", trigg.birth_date) output to console date in format:

```
<birthday>1980-01-05</birthday>
```

I need convert in format mask:

```
<birthday>05.01.1980</birthday>
```

Data about date in my datebase saved like 00.00.0000 and have type date. 
I tried used function TO_DATE(date, 'DD.MM.YYYY'), TO_TIMESTAMP but this useless

Please, tell me how convert to needed format? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to convert it FROM a date TO a CHAR, so use TO_CHAR

```
XMLELEMENT("birthday", TO_CHAR(trigg.birth_date, 'DD.MM.YYYY'))
```